# Project failed to complete the Gradle sync.

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Whenever I try to run a `gradle` sync on my project i keep getting this error:

```
Failed to refresh Gradle project 'MeetupVersion1.0'
Unable to load class 'org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.IdeDependenciesExtractor$IdeDependency'.
```

How do I fix this error? Do I have to import this class or does it have to do with my `Android Studio`?

Answer (score 4):

This tends to happen when you're trying to use a build file that specifies a version of the Android Gradle plugin that's too new for the given version of Android Studio to handle. I'd suggest updating Android Studio.

If you continue to have problems, amend you question with the version of Android Studio you're using and the contents of your build files.

This is written up in bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66325 though the bug report doesn't really have any detail other than a couple reports that people solved it by upgrading.